# How to wait until for "particular text" is present on page without knowing xpath or element id

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to wait until page is fully loaded or some text on page is visible using selenium chrome webdriver.
The problem is I can not see inspect element because It is aws terminal linux session.

Text present on page is - "sudo yum update"

Comment: Please have a look at this [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). Update the question with your code trials and relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:
you can check for the text in the page source.

```
import re  # make sure to add this package

src = driver.page_source
text_found = re.search(r'sudo yum update', src)
print (text_found)
```

Option 2:

simply use the xpath to wait for element present.

`//*[contains(.,'sudo yum update')]`

Comment: Option 1 is bad because the text could be anywhere in the source including in comments, or code.  Option 2 is better, but you would really want to have an explicit wait to make sure it is visible as well.

Comment: Thanks...Now I can access inspect element and I also got XPATH and I am using below code to wait until text loaded.Code is: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//x-row[contains(text(),'Run \"sudo yum update\" to apply all updates.')]"))); but still selenium is throwing error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //x-row[contains(text(),'Run "sudo yum update" to apply all updates.')]. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried with presence of element rather visibility?

Comment: Thanks... issue was related to frame present in window.